# Camunda Engine, task search

Tags: spring-boot, camunda

I am using Camunda version 7.19.0. I have implemented a controller that takes a TaskQueryDto to find all tasks based on specified variable criteria.

```
@RestController
public class RestEngineController {

    @Autowired
    private TaskCustomService taskCustomService;

    @PostMapping(value = "/rest-engine/task-with-variables", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    List<TaskWithVariables> getTasks(@RequestBody TaskQueryDto query,
                                     @RequestParam("firstResult") Integer firstResult,
                                     @RequestParam("maxResults") Integer maxResults) {
        return taskCustomService.getTasks(query, firstResult, maxResults);
    }
}
```

However, I’ve encountered an issue. In Camunda’s ConditionQueryParameterDto , there is no operator for “in”.

```
public class ConditionQueryParameterDto {

  public ConditionQueryParameterDto() {

  }

  public static final String EQUALS_OPERATOR_NAME = "eq";
  public static final String NOT_EQUALS_OPERATOR_NAME = "neq";
  public static final String GREATER_THAN_OPERATOR_NAME = "gt";
  public static final String GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUALS_OPERATOR_NAME = "gteq";
  public static final String LESS_THAN_OPERATOR_NAME = "lt";
  public static final String LESS_THAN_OR_EQUALS_OPERATOR_NAME = "lteq";
  public static final String LIKE_OPERATOR_NAME = "like";
  public static final String NOT_LIKE_OPERATOR_NAME = "notLike";
```

So, how can I use the “in” operator?

Answer (score 1):

As also answered here https://forum.camunda.io/t/camunda-task-search/48616/2 there is no way to do that via the REST api. So you will have to do multiple requests and combine the results.